# How to validate format of data using glob in python?

Tags: python, operating-system, conda, glob, pdftables

I have a list of different files in my folder and these files have several formats, like PDF, txt, Docx and HTML. I want to validate the format of the files in python.

Here is my attempt

```
import os
import pdftables_api
import glob    
path = r"myfolder\*"
files = glob.glob(path)
for i in files:
    if i.endswith('.pdf'):
       conversion = pdftables_api.Client('my_api')
       conversion.xlsx(i,r"destination\*")
```

The reason for this is I want to iterate through each file and check if the file is pdf, then it is pdf, convert it into excel using API from PDFTable_api package in python and save it in the destination folder. But I don't feel like this is an efficient way to do this.

Can anyone please help me if there is an efficient manner of achieving this?

Comment: What about `glob.glob('myfolder/*.pdf')`

Comment: @zamir yes I can use that, but how can I iterate through the files if I use glob.glob?